# create a python list with combinations of the first element with the rest of list without repeat tuples in a combination

Tags: python, list, tuples, combinations, python-itertools

I'm trying to create a list of tuples in python with the combinations of first element of list with the rest elements of the list but without repeat the first element of the tuple in final result of combinations

I use this:

```py
lst = [(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (3, 'error'), (4, 'ok'), (4, 'fail'), (4, 'error')]

data = [[lst[0]] + list(i) for i in itertools.combinations(lst[1:], 2)]
for i in data:
    print(i)
```

and get this:

```
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (3, 'ok')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (3, 'fail')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (3, 'error')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (4, 'ok')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (4, 'fail')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (4, 'error')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (3, 'fail')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (3, 'error')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (4, 'ok')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (4, 'fail')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (4, 'error')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'error'), (3, 'error')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'error'), (4, 'ok')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'error'), (4, 'fail')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'error'), (4, 'error')]
[(2, 'ok'), (4, 'ok'), (4, 'ok')]
[(2, 'ok'), (4, 'ok'), (4, 'fail')]
[(2, 'ok'), (4, 'ok'), (4, 'error')]
[(2, 'ok'), (4, 'fail'), (4, 'fail')]
[(2, 'ok'), (4, 'fail'), (4, 'error')]
[(2, 'ok'), (4, 'error'), (4, 'error')]
```

but y want this:

```
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (4, 'ok')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (4, 'fail')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (4, 'error')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (4, 'ok')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (4, 'fail')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (4, 'error')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'error'), (4, 'ok')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'error'), (4, 'fail')]
[(2, 'ok'), (3, 'error'), (4, 'error')]
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: The `len` of the original `lst` can be > 1000

```py
lst = [(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (3, 'error'), .... (n, 'ok'), (n, 'fail'), (n, 'error')]
```

Comment: What result do you want for `lst = [(2, 'ok'), (2, 'fail'), (3, 'ok')]`?

Comment: If there are ten different numbers, do you want tuples of length 10 or still only triples?

Comment: @KellyBundy I edit the question to clarify them, I want the result that i show in the last box with code in the question

Comment: From your example it's not clear what you want for mine, otherwise I wouldn't ask about mine.

Comment: Does your newest edit mean something like my example won't happen?

Comment: In the example of the question i print the result of combinations generated by the code, but i need just the result in the last box of the question

Comment: maybe you should split into two list - numbers and words, and use `set()` to remove duplicated values, and next generate combinations. Maybe it will need also `zip()` to create pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could group items with the same number and later use `itertool.product()`

```
import itertools

lst = [(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (3, 'error'), (4, 'ok'), (4, 'fail'), (4, 'error')]

groups = {}

for number, word in lst:
    if number not in groups:
        groups[number] = []
    groups[number].append( (number, word) )

data = groups.values()

for item in itertools.product(*data):
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
((2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (4, 'ok'))
((2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (4, 'fail'))
((2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (4, 'error'))
((2, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (4, 'ok'))
((2, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (4, 'fail'))
((2, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (4, 'error'))
((2, 'ok'), (3, 'error'), (4, 'ok'))
((2, 'ok'), (3, 'error'), (4, 'fail'))
((2, 'ok'), (3, 'error'), (4, 'error'))
```

---

**EDIT:**

You may also use `itertools.groupby(lst, lambda x:x[0])` to group items.

```
import itertools

lst = [(2, 'ok'), (3, 'ok'), (3, 'fail'), (3, 'error'), (4, 'ok'), (4, 'fail'), (4, 'error')]

groups = itertools.groupby(lst, lambda x:x[0])

data = [list(val) for key, val in groups]
#keys, data = zip(*groups)  # ???
 
for item in itertools.product(*data):
    print(item)
```

Comment: Thanks furas for your answer and point's of view, works like a charm!

Comment: @xarc You're saying both answers work, even though they do different things. How does that make sense?

Comment: @KellyBundy I test both answers and both do the work, furas's answer, a little more understandable and efficient

Comment: @xarc Kevin's answer produces triples whereas firas's produces (n-1)-tuples. Fundamentally different (just not in your example where n=4) and you refused to say which one you want.